# How do I know which commands only a root user can execute?

Tags: command-line, manpage

The exercise is to identify commands that only a root user can execute. How do I identify which commands only a root user can execute from this list?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The numbers beside the commands corresponds to what section of the manual that page is from; 1 is user commands, while 8 is sysadmin stuff.

From [`man man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man.1.html)

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

The commands in the above list with number `8` refers to commands usually only for root. But that does not mean other users can not execute those command. Other users can use those commands with some restrictions. For example `ping(8)`, if one try to Flood ping some system he will not be allowed. But simple ping is allowed.